# Catch "HTTPError 404" in python for gcloud commands

Tags: python, api, gcloud

Trying to catch this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.add-labels) HTTPError 404: The resource 'projects/matei-testing-4010-5cbdeeff/zones/us-east1-b/instances/all' was not found
```

Tried different versions of code and none worked for me.

My current code does not seem to catch an error:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors

try:
    print("Applying labels")
    gcloud_value = (f'gcloud compute instances add-labels all --labels="key=value" --zone=us-east1-b')
    process = subprocess.run([gcloud_value], shell=True)
except errors.HttpError:
   print("Command did not succeed because of the following error: {}".format(errors.HttpError))
```

How do I catch the error to use it later?

Thank you

Comment: The return value from the subprocess will just be the executable's exit code **unless** you get the standard output/error and analyse that. You certainly will not be able to trap an HttpError exception in the way that you were hoping

Comment: What i am trying to achieve with this is to take a note after the error that this resource does not exist. I had the same feeling as you said, but how would i achieve what i want with getting the stdout/stderr, do you have a small example with python? Is there a way like grepping the error text to tag it as an error? Or any ideeas? Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
import subprocess
gcloud_value = 'gcloud compute instances add-labels all --labels="key=value" --zone=us-east1-b'
process = subprocess.run(gcloud_value, shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(process.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
print(process.stderr.decode('utf-8'))
print(process.returncode)
```

One would expect gcloud to emit errors to stderr. Therefore by examining process.stderr you should be able to figure out what (if anything) has gone wrong. Also, if process.returncode is non-zero you should be able to deduce that it didn't work but that depends entirely on how the underlying application (gcloud in this case) is written. There's plenty of stuff out there that returns zero even when there was a failure!